# What's the difference between return -code error and error

Tags: tcl

What is actually the difference between raising an exception in TCL via `return -code error ...`and `error ...`? When would one be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `error` command produces an error right at the current point; it's great for the cases where you're throwing a problem due to a procedure's internal state.
The `return -code error` command makes the procedure it is placed in produce an error (as if *the procedure* was `error`); it's great for the case where there's a problem with the arguments passed to the procedure (i.e., the caller did something wrong).
The difference really comes when you look at the stack trace.

Here's a (contrived!) example:

```
proc getNumberFromFile {filename} {
    if {![file readable $filename]} {
        return -code error "could not read $filename"
    }
    set f [open $filename]
    set content [read $f]
    close $f
    if {![regexp -- {-?\d+} $content number]} {
        error "no number present in $filename"
    }
    return $number
}

catch {getNumberFromFile no.such.file}
puts $::errorInfo
#could not read no.such.file
#    while executing
#"getNumberFromFile no.such.file"

catch {getNumberFromFile /dev/null}
puts $::errorInfo
#no number present in /dev/null
#    while executing
#"error "no number present in $filename""
#    (procedure "getNumberFromFile" line 9)
#    invoked from within
#"getNumberFromFile /dev/null"
```

Comment: There are also differences if you use `catch` inside the procedure to trap the two different cases, but that's getting a lot more complex.

Comment: Probably it's also worth mentioning that since Tcl 8.5 `return` learned the `-level` option which could be used to raise an error somewhere higher up the stack, which can be used when implementing custom complex commands (usually pretending to form a DSL). `error` can't do that.